# Want to change ForegroundColor with input from user

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I want to make a textbased game where at the start you can choose what color your character shall have. I have searched everywhere but can't seem to find anything!
Here is my code (its probably trash since I started 4 hours ago)
Whenever I have the main character speak I write "Player();" a line before my Console.WriteLine("XXXXXX");

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Adventure_game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Start
            menuspeaker();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to -- (by: Patrick Sørensen)");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Note: You can escape the anytime by pressing ESC, but be careful you can not save and any progress will be lost!");
            Thread.Sleep(8000);
            Console.WriteLine("First of all select your color!");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Type 1 for Blue");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Type 2 for White");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Type 3 for Green");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Type 4 for Red");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Type 5 for Yellow");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Type 6 for Purple");
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '1')
            {
                var Player = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You have choosen BLUE!");
            }
            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '2')
            {
                var Player = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You have choosen WHITE!");
            }
            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '3')
            {
                var Player = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You have choosen GREEN!");
            }
            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '4')
            {
                var Player = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You have choosen RED!");
            }
            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '5')
            {
                var Player = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You have choosen YELLOW!");
            }
            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '6')
            {
                var Player = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You have choosen PURPLE!");
            }

            menuspeaker();
            Console.WriteLine("Write Ready when you are ready to begin");

            menuanswer();
            string readyString = Console.ReadLine();

            //Ready command
            if (readyString.ToLower() == "ready")
            {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

            //Navn
            menuspeaker();
            Console.WriteLine("Before we begin the story, tell me, what is your name?");
            menuanswer();
            string nameString = Console.ReadLine();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            menuspeaker();
            Console.WriteLine(""+nameString+"?");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("What a wounderfull name!");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Okay, now we can begin with our adventure!");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Please wait");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.Clear();

            //Start på spillet
            Fred();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Fred: Hurry up "+nameString+" the king is waiting!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //The Player will speak here vv
            Console.WriteLine(""+nameString+": Why are we in such a hurry? What has happend?");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Fred();
            Console.WriteLine("Fred: I don't know, when the alarm went off the guards requested you in the throne room");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            menuspeaker();
            Console.WriteLine("Fred and "+nameString+" entered the the big throne room and on the throne sat the King nervous");
            Thread.Sleep(6000);
            King();
            Console.WriteLine("King: I have been waiting quite a while for you " + nameString + " and Fred, how come");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Fred();
            Console.WriteLine("Fred: I had a hard time finding " + nameString + ", why did the alarm go off?");
            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            King();
            Console.WriteLine("King: The princess have been taken by a Big monster!");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("And i want you Fred and " + nameString + " go find the Monsters");



        }
        static void menuspeaker()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        }
        static void menuanswer()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        }
        static void Fred()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        }
        static void Player()
        {

        }
        static void King()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        }
        static void Monster()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, Can you please explain your problem a little better

Comment: What shall i write to get my main character to have the color i choose? I have different colors for every person in the game

Comment: You mean you have many players that play at sametime and take there chance one by one??

Comment: No, its a single player game and no save (so far). As i said i want the player to choose a color and whenever the players character "speaks" i want the console to write that text in the color the player choose :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to do is *link* the colors to the players at the beginning of the program, and remember it throughout the program. Then, whenever a particular player *speaks*, you set the console color, and after speaking, set it back.

So let's say you have a simple class `Player` like so:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; }

    public void Speak(string speech)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = Color;
        Console.WriteLine(speech);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
}
```

Now each player has a `Name` and a `ConsoleColor` assosiated, and whenever the `Speak()` is called, console will be set to that players color, write the speech, then set it back to white (assuming white is the default color).

In your main program, now you can probably ask for `Name` and `Color`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var player = new Player();
    Console.Write("Enter Name : ");
    var name = Console.ReadLine();
    player.Name = name;

    Console.WriteLine("First of all select your color!");
    Console.WriteLine("Type 1 for Blue");
    Console.WriteLine("Type 2 for Green");
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

    if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '1')
    {
        player.Color = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    }
    if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '2')
    {
        player.Color = ConsoleColor.Green;
    }

    player.Speak(string.Format("You have chosen {0}", player.Color.ToString()));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now you can extend this idea, and at the beginning of the game ask for names and colors of many players. Then, save those to a `List<Player>`, and use them throughout.

---

### EDIT

You can even include the getting information from the user into the `Player` class so it's neater cleaner code, and less error prone. You'd include this method to the `Player` class:

```
public void GetPlayerInfo()
{
    Console.Write("Enter Name : ");
    Name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Pick a Color : ");
    Console.WriteLine("1 : Red");
    Console.WriteLine("2 : Blue");
    Console.WriteLine("3 : Green");
    var key = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (key)
    {
        case "1":
            Color = ConsoleColor.Red;
            break;
        case "2":
            Color = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            break;
        case "3":
            Color = ConsoleColor.Green;
            break;
        default:
            Color = ConsoleColor.White;
            break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Then at the main end all you have to do is call the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var player1 = new Player();
    player1.GetPlayerInfo();
    player1.Speak(string.Format("You have chosen {0}", player1.Color.ToString()));
    var player2 = new Player();
    player2.GetPlayerInfo();
    player2.Speak(string.Format("You have chosen {0}", player2.Color.ToString()));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: +1: I was just about to create this answer when you posted. This would've been the same route I would've taken.

Comment: I have edited my post so you can see my whole code i know there is a static void at the buttom with "Player();". im new to programming (started today) and dont really have a clue what you write

Comment: If you're new to programming I encourage you to learn the concept of `class` as soon as you can. It's very powerful and, hence, useful. There're tons of resources online. Once you learn them you'll see this problem/game can be created much easier with them.

Comment: Hello again Sach i think i did what you said, but in my "static void Main(string[] args)" it cant seem to find Speak()

Comment: `Speak()` is a method associated with the class `Player`, so you need to create an instance of that class as I've done (`var player = new Player()`), and then call the method assosiated with that instance (`player.Speak()`). Please try to read up and learn more about classes.